# Multiple infrared proximity sensors and Arduino

Tags: arduino, sensor, infrared

I am wondering if it's possible to connect multiple infrared proximity sensors as this one
http://www.adafruit.com/products/1568
to an arduino uno. I would need to connect 5 of them pointing in different directions.

Should i use an external power supply for each of them to be sure they are all running at 5V? Should i be aware of something else or it should be just plug and play as if i was using just one sensor?
Thank you very much for your support. Any suggestion is higly appreciated!

---

Ok thank you very much for your answers. So a connection diagram like the one attached should work?
Thank you again for your help

!Multiple infrared sensors connection diagram
[IMAGE DIAGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuT1A.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

This should work, with each sensor connected to its own ADC input.

Although the data sheet indicates that the typical current is 30 mA, there is a note at the very end of the datasheet that it actually requires about 330 mA peak current, so you should use a power supply rated at 1.7 amps or more.

Comment: Ok so it should be enough to power each sensor indipendently and just connect each Vo (signal) cable to arduino?

Comment: Excuse me just another question...why should i have at least 1.7 amps to handle safely 330 mA peak current?

Comment: If you use a single power supply for all the sensors, the sensors could possibly all demand 350 mA at the same time - perhaps not likely, but possible.  It may be possible to use a lower-current supply, but only tests will tell for sure.

Comment: Yes, each sensor should be connected to its own analog port. As an alternative, you could use an analog multiplexer and a couple of digital control lines, so you could scan through all of the sensors with one analog input port - useful when you are low on I/O or want to add a LOT of sensors.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your answers. So a connection diagram like the one attached should work? Thank you again for your help http://i.stack.imgur.com/zuT1A.jpg

Comment: Yes (although I'd prefer a real schematic rather than a Fritzing connection diagram).  The Adafruit page for the sensors indicate that a 220uF capacitor is supplied with each one - these capacitors should be connected across the supply leads as close as practical to each sensor.  The capacitors will supply much of the peak pulse current that the sensors apparently require.